# Clipping graphics of ellipsoids

Tags: graphics

Say I have the following code to generate a graphics object

```
data = {
   {{0.46, 0.43}, 0.73},
   {{0.46, 0.90}, 0.63},
   {{0.97, 0.93}, 0.83},
   {{0.97, 0.43}, 0.65},
   {{0.46, -0.06}, 0.83},
   {{0.97, -0.06}, 0.70},
   {{-0.07, 0.90}, 0.50},
   {{-0.03, 0.43}, 0.90},
   {{-0.05, -0.06}, 0.55}
   };
n = Length[data];
p = data[[All, 1]];
\[Theta] = data[[All, 2]];
Graphics[
 {
  Table[Rotate[{
     LightGray,
     EdgeForm[Black],
     Ellipsoid[p[[k]], {0.3, 0.2}]
     }, \[Theta][[k]], p[[k]]], {k, n}],
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]
  }
 , PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 1.3}, {-0.4, 1.2}}
 ]
```

The representation of the generated object is as follows:

[image]

How can I clip out the gray part of the ellipsoids external to the square box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ellipsoids = Table[TransformedRegion[Ellipsoid[p[[k]], {0.3, 0.2}], 
    RotationTransform[θ[[k]], p[[k]]]], {k, n}];

insiderectangle = DeleteCases[_EmptyRegion] @
  Map[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionIntersection[#, Rectangle[]] &]@
  ellipsoids;

Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], elipsoids, 
   FaceForm[LightGray], insiderectangle },
 Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 1.3}, {-0.4, 1.2}}]
```

[image]

To get the portions of elliposids that lie outside the unit rectangle use `RegionDifference` in place of `RegionIntersection`:

```
outsiderectangle = DeleteCases[_EmptyRegion] @
   Map[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionDifference[#, Rectangle[]] &]@
    ellipsoids;

Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Black], 
   FaceForm[LightBlue], outsiderectangle, 
   FaceForm[LightRed], insiderectangle}, 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 1.3}, {-0.4, 1.2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but please read my comment to the other answer

Comment: please see the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Graphics[{Table[
   Rotate[{LightGray, EdgeForm[Black], 
     Ellipsoid[p[[k]], {0.3, 0.2}]}, \[Theta][[k]], p[[k]]], {k, n}], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

If you switch to `Frame-> True` then you can see the `PlotRange` you need. For some reason you had too wide a plot range.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, I would like to have also the external part of the image, with ellipsoid's border but without gray